# How can I store values in a hashmap with <String, List<Integer>>

Tags: java, hashmap

I have the following array

I am trying to save the array information in a hashmap.

```
String[][] students = {{"Bobby", 87}, {"Charles", 100}, {"Eric", 64}, 
                               {"Charles", 22}};

Map<String, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
List<Integer> score1 = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i=0; i<students.length; i++) {
    score1.add(students[i][1]);
    map.put(students[i][0], score1);
}
```

But i want to store the information in the map key value pair.

Expected output:

```
"Bobby" -> 87
"Charles" -> 100,22
"Eric" -> 64
```

Actual output:

```
{Charles=[87, 100, 64, 22], Eric=[87, 100, 64, 22], Bobby=[87, 100, 64, 22]}
```

how can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Using java-8 you could use the following all in a single line :

```
Map<String, List<Integer>> collect1 = 
     Arrays.stream(students).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(arr -> arr[0], 
              Collectors.mapping(arr -> Integer.parseInt(arr[1]), Collectors.toList())));
```

Here we group by the 0th index for the name of the student and the 1st index will hold the marks of the student.

Answer (score 2):

You need to differentiate between already exist and new array:

```
 List<Integer> currScore = map.get(students[i][0])
 if (currScore != null) {
   currScore.add(students[i][1]);
 } else {
    List<Integer> newScore = new ArrayList<>();
    newScore.add(students[i][1]);
    map.put(students[i][0], newScore);
 }
```

Also change variables names to meaningful names

Answer (score 2):

You can check why your original code won't even compile here: https://ideone.com/AWgBWl

After several fixes to your code this is a correct way of doing it (following your logic):

```
// values should be like this {"Bobby", "87"} because you declared it as
// an array of strings (String[][]), this {"Bobby", 87} is a String and an int
String[][] students = {{"Bobby", "87"}, {"Charles", "100"}, {"Eric", "64"}, {"Charles", "22"}};
// the inner list must be of Strings because of the previous comment
Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
// list of strings because of the previous comment
List<String> score1;

for(int i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
    score1 = map.get(students[i][0]);     // check if there is a previously added list
    if (score1 == null) {
        score1 = new ArrayList<>();      // create a new list if there is not one previously added for that name
        map.put(students[i][0], score1);
    }
    map.get(students[i][0]).add(students[i][1]); // add a new value to the list inside the map
}
System.out.println(map.toString());
// {Charles=[100, 22], Eric=[64], Bobby=[87]}
```

Demo here: https://ideone.com/SJpTHs

Answer (score 2):

```
String[][] students = { { "Bobby", "87" }, { "Charles", "100" }, { "Eric", "64" }, { "Charles", "22" } };
Map<String, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
Stream.of(students).forEach(student -> map.computeIfAbsent(student[0], s -> new ArrayList<>()).add(Integer.parseInt(student[1])));
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you initialize you list outside the loop and use it for all appends, all entries in your `hashmap` are referencing the same instance. For each entry in students, you need to check if you already have a list for that student. If so, retrieve that particular list and append to it. If not, create a new list and then append. The code inside you for loop will look something like the following:

```
String name = students[i][0];
List<Integer> scores = map.get(name);
if (scores == null) {
    scores = new ArrayList<>();
}
scores.add(students[i][1]);
map.put(name, scores);
```